# Is it possible to reuse HTML like a template on multiple pages?

Tags: html

I have several pages on a website that use the same header for each page. I was wondering if there was some way to simply reference a file with the html for the header sort of like in this pseudo code:

```
<!-- Main Page -->

<body>
  <html_import_element src = "myheadertemplate.html">
<body>
```

Then in a separate file:

```
<!-- my header template html -->

<div>
  <h1>This is my header</h1>
  <div id = "navbar">
    <div class = "Tab">Home</div>
    <div class = "Tab">Contact</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way I could write the header html once and just import it in each of my pages where I need it by writing one simple tag. Is this possible? Can I do this with XML?

Comment: not with pure html. But you most server side languages supports some type of ***include*** capability. What server will you be hosting your site on? (*you could also use JS to do it but it would not be search engine friendly*)

Comment: You can do this client side, using a templating library such as `Underscore.js` - see link here : - http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: underscorejs is WAY too big for something like this, a simple ajax request would suffice...In jquery that would look like: ``$.get("header.htm", function(data) {$("#header").html(data);});``

Comment: I'm using NodeJS. It would probably be easy enough to do with node, but I was just wondering if there was an element that could handle this. I was hoping to stay away from Javascript and JQuery, though.

Comment: *"I was just wondering if there was an element that could handle this"* There is not.

Comment: Staying away from javascript? This is the 21st century, websites can be interacted with besides being just text these days :P

Comment: @FelixKling Technically you're wrong, the frame element was actually made just for that purpose in the past but is now deprecated since server side code is a way better way of doing it.

Comment: I am aware of the usefulness of Javascript and JQuery, I just wanted to know if there was an element for this. I'll probably just use Javascript if I can't find an answer, but if there was a simpler way, of course I'm going to try and find it.

Comment: @seahorsepip: You are right, completely forgot about frames... but yeah, we wouldn't want to suggest deprecated features, so "no" is still both correct and incorrect :P

Comment: @Frank just use nodejs require function server side in your case ^^ This means the client doesn't need any js whatsoever.

Comment: I believe that is what I will do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, after a long time I actually found a way to do this using AJAX. HTML Imports are a great solution, but the support across browsers is severely lacking as of 04/2017, so I came up with a better solution. Here's my source code:

```js
function HTMLImporter() {}

HTMLImporter.import = function (url) {
  var error, http_request, load, script;

  script =
    document.currentScript || document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1];

  load = function (event) {
    var attribute, index, index1, new_script, old_script, scripts, wrapper;

    wrapper = document.createElement("div");
    wrapper.innerHTML = this.responseText;

    scripts = wrapper.getElementsByTagName("SCRIPT");

    for (index = scripts.length - 1; index > -1; --index) {
      old_script = scripts[index];

      new_script = document.createElement("script");
      new_script.innerHTML = old_script.innerHTML;

      for (index1 = old_script.attributes.length - 1; index1 > -1; --index1) {
        attribute = old_script.attributes[index1];
        new_script.setAttribute(attribute.name, attribute.value);
      }

      old_script.parentNode.replaceChild(new_script, old_script);
    }

    while (wrapper.firstChild) {
      script.parentNode.insertBefore(
        wrapper.removeChild(wrapper.firstChild),
        script
      );
    }

    script.parentNode.removeChild(script);

    this.removeEventListener("error", error);
    this.removeEventListener("load", load);
  };

  error = function (event) {
    this.removeEventListener("error", error);
    this.removeEventListener("load", load);

    alert("there was an error!");
  };

  http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http_request.addEventListener("error", error);
  http_request.addEventListener("load", load);
  http_request.open("GET", url);
  http_request.send();
};
```

Now when I want to import HTML into another document, all I have to do is add a script tag like this:

```
<script>HTMLImporter.import("my-template.html");</script>
```

My function will actually replace the script tag used to call the import with the contents of `my-template.html` and it will execute any scripts found in the template. No special format is required for the template, just write the HTML you want to appear in your code.

Comment: But you need to add the script to every single file you want to reuse the `<head>` though, right?  I think the only way to really manage what you want to do is to implement a site with dynamic web pages where the server generates pages on the fly with the right template.

Comment: @guero64 You put the script into a separate file and use a script tag with src="sepFile.js".  Then you only need to add two script tags to each html file.  I'm not going to test this, because I would rather use a back end solution, but I'm pretty sure it would work.

Answer (score 15):

You could do it in this fashion below.

```
<head>
  <link rel="import" href="myheadertemplate.html">
</head>
```

where you could have your myheadertemplate.html

```
<div>
  <h1>This is my header</h1>
  <div id = "navbar">
    <div class = "Tab">Home</div>
    <div class = "Tab">Contact</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can then use it with JS below

```
var content = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]').import;
```

Comment: An ajax request makes more sense since above is html5 only :/ But nice code though, never knew import beyond css import myself ^^

Comment: yeah I came across sometime back while exploring WebComponents and Advanced HTML5

Comment: Actually, this is pretty much what I'm looking for. Cutting edge answer! I found a great explanation of what you're talking about here: [link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/)

Comment: Wow, this is an awesome frontend-only solution. I legitimately never saw anyone else post this method in any of the related questions here on SO. Not sure if I'm  missing something,  but I don't need the JS part for this to work

Comment: Please note that this behavior is deprecated and should no longer be used: https://caniuse.com/#feat=imports

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible. You can load the header as a webpage in a iframe element though. In the past webpages were built with frame elements to load seperate parts of a webpage, this is not recommended and support in current browsers is due to legacy.

In most cases this is done with server side languages like php with as example  `include("header.php");`.

Comment: But all the code would be html only, so there's no dynamic content. I'm using NodeJS, so I guess it wouldn't be that hard to do, but it seems like some pretty simple functionality, so I was hoping it might already exist.

Comment: I believe you can also use `<object>` tag to insert html removing the need to use an iframe.

Comment: The object tag works mostly the same as an iframe tag in this case and is only supported in modern browsers.

Comment: I would make no sense in html itself since html is a plain text xml language that should NOT be dynamic so something like ``<get data="header.html">`` should not be replaced with the html content of ``header.html``. @Frank

Answer (score 0):

I had found this solution.
On each page I added the script :

```
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
```

and the tag

```
<common-header></common-header>.
```

and everything works perfectly.

I don't know if it's very performant and efficient.

```
    ....some code...
        <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <common-header></common-header>
```

**main.js:**

```
class CommonHeader extends HTMLElement {
  
connectedCallback(){
    this.innerHTML = `
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <img class="img" src="assets/Logo2.png" alt="logo" />
        </div>
        <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="./index.html" class="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="./single.html" class="">Single</a></li>
        <li><a href="./contact.html" class="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="cta">
            <a href="" class="button">Chiamami </a>
        </div>
        <div class="hamburger"><span></span><span></span><span></span> 
        </div>
  </div> `
    }
}
customElements.define('common-header', CommonHeader)
```