# How to reuse HTML code across multiple pages?

Tags: html, css, web

I have a navbar on a multi page site I am currently working that looks like this

```
 <nav>
  <a href="/AboutMe.html/">About Me</a> 
  <a href="/Column.html/">Column</a> 
  <a href="/Photos.html/">Photos</a> 
</nav>
```

and I was wondering if there was any way to reuse this code across multiple pages on my site without having to retype the code into each individual HTML file.

Comment: Are you down to use jQuery?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to reuse HTML like a template on multiple pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387676/is-it-possible-to-reuse-html-like-a-template-on-multiple-pages)

Comment: Take a look at templating engines, like handlebars, nunjucks...