# How to include html and javascript in another page html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a file that have a navigation bar and interact with another file as css and javascript file. What I need to do it is include this code in another html page and I don't know to do this. I'm using nodejs as server side and as a front end i'm using w3.css and w3.js. Can You Help??

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a01ae3d94e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav>//code<nav>

<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: [some what same condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387676/is-it-possible-to-reuse-html-like-a-template-on-multiple-pages#comment60392652_36387676) You can take a look at this question. You can also use include tag in nodejs.

Comment: In that question they use html import and now it is deprecated

Comment: Since you are using nodejs you can require that html file https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_id

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load nav menu from an external file? (No Wamp, all code must be 'browser-side')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39447411/how-to-load-nav-menu-from-an-external-file-no-wamp-all-code-must-be-browser)

Comment: How I do if I have a button this navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

Create separate file for navigation drawer
navbar.html

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
</ul>
```

In your index.html

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nav"></div>
```

In your script.js add this

```
$(function() {

    $("#nav").load("navbar.html");

    function activeNav() {
        var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
         $("#nav ul li a").each(function(){
              if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
              $(this).addClass("active");
         });
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        activeNav();
    }, 100);

});
```

Now you can import the script.js file in other HTML and have the jquery to load the navbar. Don't forget to add id as nav like this  `<div id="nav"></div>`in the files where you want to include the navbar code.
[Referenced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39448407/5235168)

Comment: How I do if I have a button this navigation bar?